# Add rotation toggle to powerbutton menu?

Tags: auto-rotation

Is there any way (short of reflashing to a totally new ROM) to add a "toggle auto-rotate" or "toggle portrait/landscape" option to the menu that comes up when you press and hold the power button?

I'm endlessly fighting with auto-rotation. For whatever reason, every Android device I've owned ends up being over-eager to rotate, but stubbornly resistant to rotating BACK, even when my gestures should be making it completely obvious that I didn't want it to rotate. However, every time I disable auto-rotation, I end up finding myself in a position where I *have* to rotate to landscape for something, and have to kill even more time trying to re-enable it.

For what it's worth, I have both a Galaxy S3 and a Xoom (wi-fi) (S3 running ICS, Xoom running JB).

Comment: In short, no way of adding it except obtaining the source and modifying it, compile it and flash the freshly built ROM. Why not use [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) or [Extended Power Controls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extendedcontrols)

Comment: Hmmm. I was afraid of that. If anybody happens to know, is the code that governs the power-button menu behavior kernel-level, Touchwiz-level, or merely a normal app with source that's not intended to be user-modified, but can be trivially hacked and extended anyway as long as the phone is rooted & the partition can be mounted +rw?

Comment: Definitely not kernel-level. It might be an apk but certainly not a normal app in that sens.

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent updates to the Galaxy S III (at least Android 4.1.2) you can modify the notification panel at the top of the notifications screens that you get when you drag from the status bar. Open settings, 'Display' (under 'Device' heading) then in the 'General' heading choose 'Notification panel'.

Here you should be able to choose which Quick setting buttons you want to appear and one of them is the toggle for 'Screen rotation'.

[image]

Comment: Not what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle) from the Google Play store?
It will let you change the rotation lock from the notification screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that an app can change the power button menu. The same is true for the "power widget", a strip of toggles at the top of the notification area that some ROMs offer. You can, however, get something very close with the help of [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) -- in this case the toggles are inside an ongoing notification instead of part of the notification area.

Auto-rotate is one of the toggles included, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Notification toggles in your rom are related to the framework.apk and settings.apk. So you technically need to edit them to enable/add other toggles. You could try [Swipepad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android&hl=en) for launching/performing quick tasks.